# PHP pass array item to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm having some difficulties in passing an array item from PHP to a Javascript function.

I have a txt file which is something like this:

```
recipe1 flour milk
recipe2 egg milk
recipe3 flour salt
```

I read txt file and need to list all recipes in a list:

```
recipe1
recipe2
recipe3
```

When a user clicks on any recipe the corresponding ingredients will be shown in a textarea.

In my example I will display in textarea

```
flour milk
```

if users click on recipe1,

```
egg milk
```

if users click on recipe2, etc.

So here's my code:

This is the JavaScript which will populate the textarea with the text I will pass to it.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function addtext(text){
document.testForm.cmd.value +=text;
}
</script>
```

Here's the code which reads line by line the txt file and put

recipe1, recipe2, recipe3, etc. in an array
flour milk, egg milk, flour salt, etc. in another array.

```
<?php

$recipe=array();
$ingredient=array();

$fp=fopen("recipes.txt", "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
    $line=fgets($fp);

    $line=explode(' ', $line, 2);

    $recipe[]=$line[0];
    $ingredient[]=$line[1];

}
fclose($fp);

//Print elements
$i=0;
foreach ($recipe as $rec) {

echo '<a href="#" onclick="addtext(\''.$ingredient[$i].'\'); return false">' . $rec . '</a><br />';

$i++;

}


?>
```

Recipe list works correclty, I cannot pass $ingredient[$i] to Javascript addtext function. I've tried without success using:

```
$value = echo json_encode($ingredient[$i])
```

Any help is appreaciated,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to `json_encode()` the entire array and pass it along to JavaScript. Here's a very rudimentary example:

```
<?php

$fruits = array(
  'cherry',
  'grape',
  'orange',
);

print '<script>var fruits = ' . json_encode($fruits) . ';</script>';
```

Then in Javascript:

```
console.log(fruits);
```

will show you what you have to work with, namely:

```
["cherry", "grape", "orange"]
```

thus `fruits[1]` returns `grape`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should render the `<script>` contents, for example, like this 
(just the idea, not the exact code):

```
echo '<script language="">
      var value = ' . json_encode($ingredient[$i]) . 
      '</script>';
```